# Improve Performance of Unread Comments with SocketIO

Tags: database, react-native, web-services, mobile, socket.io

I'm building an app that have comments module on it. This comments module will have "unread comments" if user are not seeing on mobile/web app.

My implementation for now (for mobile) is I track every items that visible on the mobile devices through ***onViewableItemsChanged*** . So, when the items is visible to user for amount of time, i will emit a socket that "this commentId are read by userId X", something like that.

[image]

Emitting socket to mark as read to individual items makes the web sevices also doing an update query every time. Is it okay? Or is there any improvement that I can do? It's ok to change the ui interface or might be there is improvement inside the code.